# iOS - removeFromSuperview removing too many views

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, uiview

In my app I have my MainWindow, View1, and View2.

View1 is loaded via a button press in the MainWindow and View2 is loaded via a UITableView in View1.

So I call `[self.window addSubview:View1]` then `[self.view addSubview:View2]`.

When I close View2 with `[self.view removeFromSuperview]` I end up back act the MainWindow and not View1 for some reason.

Any ideas as to whats going on?

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure that self.view points to 'View2'. That will depend on where you are calling `[self.view removeFromSuperview]`.

If you aren't calling inside the controller for View2, then this might work anywhere else you have a reference to it:

```
[View2 removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `[self.view removeFromSuperview]` is actually removing whatever is at `self.view` not the last subview you added.

You should be using `[view2 removeFromSuperview]` instead.

Comment: I am calling [self.view removeFromSuperview] from view2's controller so this should remove view2 and not view1 also.